# UITableViewController UINavigationController

Tags: uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, unrecognized-selector

[image]

I declared a GamePicerViewController (subclass of UITableViewController) .But I got a bug in the prepareForSegue:sender: method . The console says that gamePickerViewController is a UINavigationController. Have any ideas?

I post the GamePickerViewController.h  PlayerDetailsViewController.m and the console in the pic abve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved.

```html
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"PickGame"]) {
        UINavigationController *controller = segue.destinationViewController;
        GamePickerViewController *gamePickerViewController = [controller viewControllers][0];
        gamePickerViewController.delegate = self;
        gamePickerViewController.game = _game;
    }
}
```

I forgot the line:

```html
        UINavigationController *controller = segue.destinationViewController;
```